# Best way to retire an index

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I am retiring an old elastic search index in AWS that has not received a new document since 2016. However, something is still trying to search it.

I still want deprecate this index in a manner manner where I can get back to the original state quickly.  I have created a manual snapshot of the index and it is sitting in S3.  I was planning on deleting the domain, but, from what I understand, that deletes everything billable under AWS including the end point.  As I mentioned above, I want to be able to get back to the original state of the index.  So this domain contains a series of indexes. The largest index is 20.5 Gb.  I was going to delete the large index and resize the cluster to a smaller instance size and footprint.  Will this work or will it be unsearchable?

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience using Elasticsearch on AWS, but I have an idea about your index.

You say the index has received no new documents for a long time. If this also means no deletions and no updates, you could theoretically just take this index to a new cluster, using either snapshot + restore, or a cross-cluster reindex. Continue operating your old cluster until you're sure the new one is working well.

Again - not familiar with AWS terminology, but it sounds like this approach translates to using separate "domains". First you fully ensure the new "domain" is working with the right hardware spec and data, and then delete the old "domain".

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR -> yes!

The backup to S3 will work, but the documents will be unsearchable because in order to downsize the storage you have to delete the index.
But if someday you want to restore the data from S3 back to the index, you can.

You can resize instances and storage sizes with no downtime, however, that takes a long time and you pay extra for the machines while they are resizing.
Example:
you change your storage size from 100gb to 99gb

elasticsearch service will spin up another instance, copy all your data from the old instance to the new one and then delete the old one.

same for instance sizes.

machine up, cluster sync, machine down.

while they are syncing, you pay for them.

your plan will work, es is very flexible.
if you really don't trust aws, just make a json export from the index and keep it on s3 too, just in case things go south.